# Choice parameters Jenkinsfile return first element

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, gatling

I have a jenkinsfile with the parameter's declaration following :

```
properties([
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(/*artifactDaysToKeepStr:'15',*/ artifactNumToKeepStr: '10', daysToKeepStr: '3', numToKeepStr: '5000')),
    parameters(
        [choice(choices: 'Site1\nSite2\nSite3\nSite4\nall', description: 'What site ?', name: 'site'),
        choice(choices: 'dev\ntest\nuat\nprod', description: 'What environment ?', name: 'environment')]
    ),
    pipelineTriggers([cron('* * * * *')])
])
```

And the execution following in a stage :

```
sh "mvn gatling:execute --settings $MAVEN_SETTINGS -Dgatling.simulationClass=lu.post.${params.site}Simulation -Denv.site=${params.site} -Denv.current=${params.environment}"
```

My problem is that when I run my run in Jenkins, Choices don't at the screen show and in console input I see the execution following :

```
... Dgatling.simulationClass=lu.post.Site1Simulation -Denv.site=Site1 -Denv.current=dev
```

Why choices don't show at the screen, and why is the first element returned dynamically ?

Comment: How do you "run" the job in jenkins?

Comment: I have associate the project repository git in the multibranch Pipeline, and in Jenkins, I choose my branch and click "Launch Build"

Comment: I find, I updated the jenkins file by the menu "Reply" in Jenkins to not commit change everytime. But I had to commit and my parameters in my jenkinsfile loaded in the jenkins'configuration